# wkhtmltopdf is not executable from wicked-pdf within war

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, wicked-pdf, warbler

I am trying to create a pdf using wicked-pdf from Ruby On Rails. It works great in development mode, but when I deploy in production I get the error:

```
wkhtmltopdf is not executable
```

I have the wkhtmltopdf executable located at:

```
rails_root/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386
```

Warbler is setup to include the bin folder in the war:

```
config.includes = FileList["classes/*","bin/*"]
```

I have wicked pdf configured to find the bin in the correct spot:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  :exe_path => Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-i386').to_s
}
```

I run warbler and then deploy the war on jBoss application server. When I try to generate a PDF I get the error about it not being executable. It runs fine in development mode - not in a war.

The permissions on the binary should be fine:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 username group 11446024 Apr  3 11:40 wkhtmltopdf-i386
```

Instead of manually including the wkhtmltopdf binary, I tried using wkhtmltopdf-binary gem. This too worked fine in development mode, but Wicked PDF can't find the binary in production.

**Update:** I changed the wicked-pdf config to point to the binary provided by 'wkhtmltopdf-binary' gem when in production mode. It also is getting `wkhtmltopdf is not executable` error. The path ends up being: `jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/3j001-3g0fg5-hf2xi49o-1-hf2xiuld-9q/myrailsapp.war/WEB-INF/gems/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.9.9.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_386`

Comment: Did you install `wkhtmltopdf` on your remote server?

Comment: I had the `wkhtmltopdf` binary within the rails directory and being included within the `war`. The only way I was able to get it to work was to have the `wkhtmltopdf` binary located somewhere outside of the `war`.

Comment: @lightswitch05 Looks like you have double /gems -- is that the correct directory? If you update your exe_path to take out the /gems in the example from my answer below, that might work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you install wkhtmltopdf separately or allow your gem file to install it?

I'd do the following:

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 0.9.10'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.9.9'
```

and then set the config:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: "#{ENV['GEM_HOME']}/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-#{Gem.loaded_specs['wkhtmltopdf-binary'].version}/bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_386"
}
```

This bit `#{Gem.loaded_specs['wkhtmltopdf-binary'].version}` queries your gems to find the current version if you were to ever change the version of the gem, your prod server would still be able to find the proper folder.

Comment: I ended up installing wkhtmltopdf outside of the server. Next time I'm on that machine I'll try your suggestion and update you if it works.

Comment: Whoa!  I didn't realize how long this took to answer.  Thank you Sady, this has been driving me crazy.  I previously downloaded the binary and pulled for /bin, but this seems like the 'correct' way (or at least the way I was looking for).  I'm going to add this to the wicked_pdf docs.

Comment: Two quick updates: 1) this may break under spring, since it clears the ENV['GEM_HOME'] to ''.  2) Instead, you can try to comment out the :exe_path completely. Here is the discussion: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/pull/346

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue when working with a **Rails 5.2.3** application on an **Ubuntu 18.04**.

The error displayed is this:

> Gem::Exception: can't find executable wkhtmltopdf for gem wkhtmltopdf-binary. wkhtmltopdf-binary is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?

**Here's how I solved it**:

I simply added the [wkhtmltopdf-binary](https://rubygems.org/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary) gem to the production group which already had the [wkhtmltopdf-heroku](https://rubygems.org/gems/wkhtmltopdf-heroku) in the Gemfile.

```
group :production do
 gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku'
 gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
end
```

And then installed the gem

```
bundle install --without development test
```

If you're running on a production server, please endeavour to install the libxrender1 library, since it's a dependency for wkhtmltopdf (for rendering PDFs), to avoid en error when rendering PDFs.

```
sudo apt-get install libxrender1
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**